# Composite in C++ error [no matching member function to callto 'push_back']

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns, reference, composite

Hi trying to do a simple composite and i am struggling with an error when trying to add one Compenent to the composite for training

Here is the code

Component interface **Inteface for drawing composite**

```
class ObjectInterface
{
public:
ObjectInterface() {}
virtual void draw()=0;
virtual void applyTranslation(float x,float y){}
virtual void applyRotationDirect(float angle){}
virtual void applyRotationIndirect(float angle){}
virtual void applyHomethety(float ratio){}
virtual void applyAxialSymmetry(){}
virtual void applyCentralSymmetry(){}
};
```

**One element - Line**

```
class Line : public ObjectInterface,Object2D
{
public:
    Line(string color,Point p1,Point p2);
    // Inherited method from Object2D
    float getArea();
    float getPerimeter();

    // Inherited method from ObjectInterface
    virtual void draw();
    void applyTranslation(float x,float y);
    void applyRotationDirect(float angle);
    void applyRotationIndirect(float angle);
    void applyHomethety(float ratio);
    void applyAxialSymmetry();
    void applyCentralSymmetry();

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &os, const Line &p);
 };
```

```
class Fresque : public ObjectInterface
{
public:
    Fresque();
    // Inherited method from ObjectInterface
    void draw();
    void applyTranslation(float x,float y);
    void applyRotationDirect(float angle);
    void applyRotationIndirect(float angle);
    void applyHomethety(float ratio);
    void applyAxialSymmetry();
    void applyCentralSymmetry();

    // Personal method
    bool add(ObjectInterface const &o);
    bool remove(ObjectInterface const& o);

private:
    std::vector<ObjectInterface*> objects;  // CONTAINER FOR COMPOSITE
 };
```

**cpp file for the add method**

```
bool Fresque::add(ObjectInterface const & o){
  objects.push_back(o);  //===> THE ERROR HERE
return true;
}
```

the Error :

/fresque.cpp:50: erreur : no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
    objects.push_back(o);
    ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~

The IDE is QT , i feel bad not knowing where the mistake is and I am pretty sure it's an obvious one :/.

Comment: Pointers != references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<ObjectInterface*>` is a vector of pointers to `ObjectInterface`s. `o` is an `ObjectInterface`, not an `ObjectInterface*` (pointer to `ObjectInterface`), so you need to get the address of `o`:

```
objects.push_back(&o);
```

Comment: Thx i tried it beforehand but still get an error, saw that it was because the "const" was contradictory . 
Thx you again good sir :)